# control the order of execution of tasks in a certain name space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm new to Capistrano and I was wondering how you can control the
order of execution of tasks in a certain name space.

For example, I have some extra tasks in my deploy namespace.  I wanted
deploy:bundle and deploy:assets to run before deploy:restart so I
added these lines

```
after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:bundle'
after 'deploy:bundle', 'deploy:assets'
after 'deploy:assets', 'deploy:restart'
```

I'm not sure if this how you're supposed to do it.  Please let me know
if you guys have any tips for me!

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true }
do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

 task :bundle do
   run "cd #{current_path} && bundle install"
 end

 task :assets do
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
 end

 end

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:bundle'
after 'deploy:bundle', 'deploy:assets'
after 'deploy:assets', 'deploy:restart'
```